# C# renombrar archivo creado con Excel Package

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

Hola amigos tengo aquí un método en donde construyo un excel usando el **Excel Package**, pero tengo la siguiente situación, necesito darle un nombre distinto a cada archivo que hago, este es mi códio.

```js
public string SaveCreditQuotation(SolicitudCreditoCalculadora creditQuo) {

  var response = "";
  var message = creditQuo.fullmsn.ToString();
  var mail_user = creditQuo.mail_user.ToString();
  var lapsodias = creditQuo.lapsos;
  var username = creditQuo.username;
  var totalapagar = creditQuo.totalapagar;

  DateTime dtime = new DateTime();
 int idint = RandomNumber(1, 1000000000);
        string id = idint.ToString() ;
        string filename = "cotizacion" + "_" + id + "_" + 
                           String.Format("{0:d}", dtime) + ".xls";
        var plength = creditQuo.payments.Count;  



  using(ExcelPackage excelPackage = new ExcelPackage()) {
    //Set some properties of the Excel document
    excelPackage.Workbook.Properties.Author = "xxxx";
    excelPackage.Workbook.Properties.Title = "xxxx";
    excelPackage.Workbook.Properties.Subject = "xxx";
    excelPackage.Workbook.Properties.Created = DateTime.Now;


    //Create the WorkSheet
    OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheet worksheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet 1");

    //Add some text to cell A1


    for (int i = 0; i < plength; i++) {
      worksheet.Cells[1 + i, 1].Value = creditQuo.payments[i].IndicePago;
      worksheet.Cells[1 + i, 2].Value = creditQuo.payments[i].Fecha;
      worksheet.Cells[1 + i, 3].Value = creditQuo.payments[i].Cantidad;
    }

    //Save your file
    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(@ "wwwroot\filescreated\"+filename);

    excelPackage.SaveAs(fi);
  }
  response = "";
  return response;
}
```

hice algunas ediciones y cambios en mi código, ahora me tira esto en el

```
 excelPackage.SaveAs(fi);
```

el valor de filename es :

> "cotizacion_462038704_01/01/0001.xls"

error que me lanza :

> DirectoryNotFoundException: No se puede encontrar una parte de la ruta de acceso 'C:\Users\miuser\source\repos\miproyecto\miproyecto\wwwroot\filescreated\cotizacion_462038704_01\01\0001.xls

Me manda error, alguien sabe como puedo reenombrar mi archivo creado?

Comment: ¿No sería mejor intentar resolver el error que te da cuando creas en FileInfo en lugar de intentar renombrar luego?. ¿Qué error te da?.

Comment: este error solo me lo da cuando le paso, esta variable que quiero que sea el nombre del archivo, ya cambio la pregunta y agrego el error

Comment: Cual es el valor de `filename`? intentaste almacenar `"wwwroot\filescreated\"+filename` en un `string` para ver cual es el valor que toma? ¿Cuál es la librería que estas usando para crear el excel?

Comment: Revisa el valor con el que queda: @"wwwroot\filescreated\"+filename y compartelo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno todo parecía ser un problema con las fechas, ya que algunos formatos traen `/ ó \`
entonces lo solucioné haciendo esto:

```
filename = filename.Replace("/","_");
```

Y listo así la fecha ya era un problema para guardar el archivo

Answer (score 0):

Si estas en un ambiente web con asp.net se usa el

```
string pathFile = Server.MapPath("~/filescreated/file.xlsx");
```

para tener la ruta fisica en base a una virtual

Ahora bien si vas a crear varios archivos creo que deberias generarlo con distinto nombre y no pisar el anterior

```
string basePath = Server.MapPath("~/filescreated");
string fileName = string.Format("file_{0:yyyyMMdd_HHmmss}.xlsx", DateTime.Now);

string fullPath = Path.Combine(basePath, fileName);
```

asi agregar una fecha y hora para que cada archivo sea diferente